# Combinatorics - Probability of given two cards next to each other (Total cards = 13)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[image]

There is a set of 13 cards, numbered from 1 to 13. What is the probability that when these cards are **randomly** laid out in a line, **Card-1** and **Card-2** will be next to each other?

The given answer (from CK12.org) is   $1/{13 \choose 2}=\frac{1}{78}$ which does not make sense to me.

My answer is;

- Total permutations = $13!$
- Permutations with Card-1 and Card-2 next to each other = Put card-1 and card-2 to a bigger single card, so there are 12 cards, therefore $12!$ permutations. However, within the bigger card, there are $2!$ permutations, so  $2\cdot12!$ permutations where card-1 and card-2 are next to each other.

Therefore the probability = $\frac{2\cdot12!}{13!}=\frac{2}{13}$.

Can anyone help me understand where I have gone wrong?

Comment: If you transcribed the problem correctly, then the answer is 2/13.

Comment: The answer $1/78$ is the probability that the two given cards occupy positions 1,2 (or any particular pair of positions). There are $12$ such pairs of adjacent positions giving $12$ disjoint events whose union has probability $12*(1/78)= 2/13$ as you correctly computed.

Comment: Thanks Ned and DanielV

Comment: +1 (also) to your question, because of the following statement: "Put card-1 and card-2 to a bigger single card, so there are 12 cards".  **Yes**!  This type of approach is often very helpful in problems of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

You have not gone wrong; the answer sheet has.

The probability for obtaining the adjacency (as you argued) when selecting any two among thirteen places is: $\left.{^{12}{\mathrm C}_1}\middle/{^{13}{\mathrm C}_2}\right.$ which is indeed $\tfrac{2}{13}$ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a screenshot from CK12

Comment: I added a screenshot, however, it is not there now. Moreover, it appears that  my question has been better formatted (which I can't remember doing)

Answer (score 1):

These are other ways to compute the probability:

$12$ cards (excluding Card - 2) are laid out randomly in a line. You then put Card - 2 between any two cards or at either ends of the line so there are $13$ possibilities. Out of these, only if you put Card - 2 on the left or right of Card - 1 will they be next to each other. Probability $\frac{2}{13}$

Let $a$ denote the number of cards to the left of both cards in interest, $b$ the number of cards between them, and $c$ the number of cards to the right of both of them. $a+b+c=11,\phantom{x}a,b,c\geq 0$. Using stars and bars we get $\binom{11+3-1}{3-1}$ possibilities. If the cards are next to each other, there won’t be any cards between them i.e. $b=0\leftrightarrow a+c=11,\phantom{x}a,c\geq0$. Stars and bars give $\binom{11+2-1}{2-1}$ possibilities. Probability $\binom{11+2-1}{2-1}/\binom{11+3-1}{3-1}=\frac{2}{13}$.

I prefer the later method because can use it for more complicated problems e.g. if we want to calculate probability of any 2 of 5 cards to be next to each other if there are a total of 20 cards.

Comment: //if we want to calculate the probability of any 2 of 5 cards to be next to each other if there are a total of 20 cards//

Can this be done as below?
20! - (none of the 5 cards are next to each other)
...................
How to find None of the 5 cards next to each other?
(1): The other 15 cards are laid out on a line = 15!. Multiply this by,
(2): There are now 16 gaps including both ends. We can place the 5 cards in these 16 gaps = 16P5.

Comment: @Surm yes that is correct

Comment: @Surm now what is the probability that any 2 of 5 cards are separated by at least 2 card